# php skip empty array

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, email-attachments

I have a form(page2) with 2 checkboxes when a user selects checkbox 1 the script on the 3rd page will send instructions 1 to the emailaddress. When chkbox 2 is selected it sends instructions2.

This is working but i also get errors like filename cannot be empty when only 1 chkbox is checked.

this is the code from page 2

```
    <form name="form" method="POST" action="instructies_verzenden2.php"> 
    <p></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="i_allinonewebsolution" value="file_1.txt"><span       class="info-image information">All-in-One Websolution</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="i_custommade" value="file_2.txt"><span class="info-image information">Custom Made</span>
    <input type="hidden" name="keyfield" value="<?php echo $domeinnaam?>"><input type="hidden" name="emailadres" value="<?php echo $data2[emailadres]?>"><input type="submit"  class="sub-small sub-opslaan green" value="Update gegevens">
    <p></p>
    </form>
```

this is the code from page 3

```
    // array with filenames to be sent as attachment
    $i_allinonewebsolution=$_POST['i_allinonewebsolution'];
    $i_custommade=$_POST['i_custommade'];
    $files = array("$i_allinonewebsolution","$i_custommade");

    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
    $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
    $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
    fclose($file);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }
```

I think the problem is here:

```
    // array with filenames to be sent as attachment
    $i_allinonewebsolution=$_POST['i_allinonewebsolution'];
    $i_custommade=$_POST['i_custommade'];
    $files = array("$i_allinonewebsolution","$i_custommade");
```

I have tried to use implode and array_filter but i am doing that wrong i guess.
Thanks for any help.

## UPDATE

I have added the form pages to jsfiddle. there are 3 pages links are in the first jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BNDfg/3/

Comment: make sure POST values are not empty, try a simple if condition like if(empty($_POST['i_allinone']) && empty($_POST['custommade'])) before you proceed into actual logic on page 2

Comment: if(isset($_post['i_allinonewebsolution'])) { $i_allinonewebsolution = $_POST["i_allinonewebsolution"]; }
if(isset($_post['i_custommade'])) { $i_custommade = $_POST["i_custommade"]; }
$files = array("$i_allinonewebsolution","$i_custommade");

this gave me the error twice

Comment: Are you testing this in localhost ?

Comment: no on life website but i cant share login details i can send the pages to email

Comment: Hey i dont mean about login credentials, Some time while trying on xampp localhost warnings or errors such as if any of the POST values are not assigned can be eliminated.

Comment: I have added the full code from the pages to jsfiddle please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/BNDfg/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$files = array();
if(isset($_POST['i_allinonewebsolution'])) {
   array_push($files, $_POST['i_allinonewebsolution']);
}
if(isset($_POST['i_custommade'])) {
   array_push($files, $_POST['i_custommade']);
}
```

If you are wanting to scale this and have more check boxes you could put them in an array like

```
$checkboxes = array('i_allinonewebsolution',
                    'i_custommade',
                    'i_checkbox3',
                    'i_checkbox4');

$files = array();

foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox){
    if(isset($_POST[$checkbox])) {
       array_push($files, $_POST[$checkbox]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i_allinonewebsolution'])
} it gives an error on the }

I dont know why?

Comment: Missed the semi-colons sorry

Comment: Number one rule of PHP development, if you get an error you probably missed a semi-colon.

Comment: Thats it I will update the description above with your solution many thanks. I assume that when i need to add 30 more checkboxes i just keep adding the IF } for each checkbox.

Comment: Yeah you could do that but I'll add some more code for scalability

Answer (score 0):

When I do similar things with DB queries (where results can commonly be NULL in Select queries) I do a test to see if the variable has been set.

Use isset to test if data was actually posted.

e.g.

```
if(isset($var))
//Do Action
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: i have done this. but it still gives errors.

$files = array("$i_allinonewebsolution","$i_custommade");
if(isset($files))

Answer (score 0):

make sure POST values are not empty, try a simple if condition like if(empty($_POST['i_allinone']) && empty($_POST['custommade'])) before you proceed into actual logic on page 2

You can also use **null**, **is_set** etc to check if the **POST** or **REQUEST** values are empty

```
 $i_allinonewebsolution=$_POST['i_allinonewebsolution'];
$i_custommade=$_POST['i_custommade'];
if(!empty($i_allinonewebsolution))
{
$files = array("$i_allinonewebsolution");
}
if(!empty($i_custommade))
{
$files = array("$i_custommade");
}
if(!empty($i_allinonewebsolution) && !empty($i_custommade))
{
$files = array("$i_allinonewebsolution","$i_custommade");
}
```

Just give a try ! Sorry for extended code.

Comment: i dont understand the code. when it is empty it just needs to ignore. I have no idea how to implement the if else into the code i posted.

Comment: This wouldn't scale very well if more checkboxes were to be added.

Comment: Yeah i agree with you. I just tried to explian how to overcome the current scenario..